# ConTeXt: cannot use \starttyping in custom start-stop environment

Tags: errors, context, context-mkiv

I wanted to have a custom start-stop environment taking a parameter. `\definestartstop` does not seem able to do that, but I found a [post on the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2007/025969.html) and tried to use that code:

```
\long\def\startMyEnv[#1]#2\stopMyEnv{%
  \starttext
  #1\blank[1cm]
  #2
  \stoptext
}

\let\stopMyEnv\relax

\startMyEnv[1]
  \starttyping
    foo
  \stoptyping
\stopMyEnv
```

This yields the following error when compiling:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 14 in file /.../test.tex: ! Interruption                                                                         


\doifelsenextoptionalcs ...t \m_syst_action_yes #1                                                        
                                                  \let \m_syst_action_nop #2...                           
\buff_verbatim_typing_stop ...gparameter \c!after                                                         
                                                  \useindentnextparameter \t...                           
\startMyEnv ...yEnv ->\starttext #1\blank [1cm] #2                                                        
                                                   \stoptext                                              
l.14     \stopMyEnv
```

It works when I do not use `\starttyping` inside the environment.

I also tried doing the additional wraparound mentioned in the post:

```
\def\startMyEnv{\dosingleempty\doStartMyEnv}

\long\def\doStartMyEnv[#1]#2\stopMyEnv{%
```

But the error stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\start...\stoptyping` changes category codes.  Passing this as an argument to another macro (here `\start...\stopMyEnv`) never works well.  Therefore, you don't want `\start...\stopMyEnv` to take the content as a parameter.  Also you might want to check whether the optional parameter is empty.

```
\def\startMyEnv{\dosingleempty\dostartMyEnv}
\def\dostartMyEnv[#1]{%
  \starttext
  \iffirstargument
    #1\blank[1cm]
  \fi
}
\let\stopMyEnv\stoptext

\startMyEnv[1]
  \starttyping
    foo
  \stoptyping
\stopMyEnv
```

[image]

*Addendum:*  Because it is not possible to pass verbatim content as an argument to a macro, the `\start...\stoptext` pair is also *not* defined as

```
\def\starttext#1\stoptext{...}
```

but rather as two single macros taking no arguments (see [`file-job.mkvi`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/file-job.mkvi#L133))

```
\unexpanded\def\starttext{\clf_starttext}
\unexpanded\def\stoptext{\clf_stoptext}
```